Keycloak and ASP.NET Core Web API : multiple realm authentication or dynamcially load Keycloak configuration for each realm?
This code works:
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddKeycloakWebApi(configuration);

services.AddAuthorization()
.AddKeycloakAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.EnableRolesMapping = RolesClaimTransformationSource.Realm;
    // Note, this should correspond to role configured with KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
    options.RoleClaimType = KeycloakConstants.RoleClaimType;
});

And I have these settings:
"Keycloak": {
  "realm": "realm1",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "private-client",
  "verify-token-audience": false,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "yoursecxxxyyy"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {
    "credentials": {}
  }
},

Now say I have another realm realm2. Could I be able to use both?
Keycloak and .NET Core multi realm authentication, or can I dynamcially load Keycloak configuration for each realm? Is this even possible?

It is possible to change service configuration after application run by using IOptionsMonitor.
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ValuesController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this._serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        [HttpGet("changeConfig")]
        public void change()
        {
            //Get IOptionsMonitor of target options, then get options from the corresponding auth scheme 
            var keyCloakAuthenticationOptionsMonitor = _serviceProvider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<KeycloakAuthenticationOptions>>();
            var keyCloakAuthenticationOptions = keyCloakAuthenticationOptionsMonitor.Get(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            //Then you could change the keycloak options as you like
            keyCloakAuthenticationOptions.Credentials.Secret = "xxx";
        }
    }

(Becareful if you inject IOptionsMonitor directly, it won't work.)
